# How to make semantic input with text choice and arrow behavior like number input

Tags: css, html, semantic-markup

[image: high-low range]

I'm looking to make inputs like this with choices low/medium/high and have arrow controls similar to `input[type=number]`. What's a semantic way to code this?

Comment: Semantically, and considering user-friendliness, the best option is sticking with the good ol' `<select>`. People are used to standards on the web; they are aware that different options are represented as a drop-down. Additionally, it might be confusing have this type of behaviour for String values. A user'd have to click the up arrow x times before realising there's no more values in that direction (with numbers it's kind of straightforward). I don't think that this implementation would be a good idea, but I'm just leaving it here as a comment so you can obviously decide what you'll do.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be semantic and accessible; But also keep this design;
Your best choice is to use `input[type=radio]` and `label[for]`.

You'll have to use `:checked` pseudo-attribute and `~` adjacent selectors.

Here is a working snippet, I didn't spent time on design.

```css
.almost-select {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #EEE;
  border: #CCC solid;
  border-radius: .2rem;
}
.almost-select input,
.almost-select output{
  display: none;
}
.almost-select .buttons {
  display: inline-block;
  border-left: inherit;
}
.almost-select label {
  font-size: .5em;
}

.almost-select #temp_high:checked ~ output[for='temp_high'] {
  display: inline-block;
}
.almost-select #temp_low:checked ~ output[for='temp_low'] {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
    <div class='almost-select'>
      <input type='radio' name='temp' id='temp_high' checked />
      <input type='radio' name='temp' id='temp_low' />
      <output for='temp_high'>High</output>
      <output for='temp_low'>Low</output>
      <div class='buttons'>
        <label for='temp_high'>▲</label>
        <label for='temp_low'>▼</label>
      </div>
    </div>
```

But how many options do you have ?
If you have a select with many many options, it will result in a really big CSS...

Comment: The bonus is that you can do something with checkboxes to simulate multiple choices select.